# Program R: How to create loop to process parts of data set based on levels?

Tags: r, loops, batch-processing

I have dataset that is listed as such:

.

```
data <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("I", "II", "III"), class = "factor"), 
    time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), species = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
    "c", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("group", "time", 
"species"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
head(data)


##     group time species
## 1     I    1       a
## 2     I    1       b
## 3     I    1       c
## 4     I    2       b
## 5     I    2       d
## 6     I    3       a
```

I am creating co-occurrence tables for the species that co-occur in the same time-blocks. The code exemplified here creates a co-occurrence table for species found in group I:

```
data2=subset(data,data$group=="I")    
X =table(data2$species,data2$time)    
X <- as.matrix(X)    
out <- X %*% t(X)

write.table(out,"coocurrence_groupI.txt",sep="\t")
```

My original data set actually has a great amount of groups; subsetting each one and then creating a .txt file seems too redundant. My Question is how can I create a looping function that automatically creates co-occurrence tables for each group (I,II and III in the example) and then writes different .txt files for each ?

I scoured the internet and haven't found anything close, with exceptions for sapply (which I am not entirely sure is the right operation).
 Perhaps I haven't looked in the right places. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kmkross

Comment: Look at the [`plyr` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) or  [`data.table`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) or a combination of `split` and `lapply`

Answer (score 1):

I'm partial to the `split` `apply` methods of solving these sorts of problems though as mnel points out there are alternatives.

I'd turn your matrix thing into a function and then split the data by group and lapply that function to each group as seen below:

```
#your data renamed dat (data is an R function so avoid using that as a name
dat <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("I", "II", "III"), class = "factor"), 
    time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), species = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
    "c", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("group", "time", 
"species"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"
))

#your processing turned into a function
FUN <- function(DATA) {
    X <- table(DATA[, 2],DATA[, 1])    
    X <- as.matrix(X)    
    X %*% t(X)
}

#the split lapply method
X <- split(dat[, 2:3], dat[, 1])    
lapply(X, FUN)
```

**This yields:**

```
$I

    a b c d
  a 2 1 1 0
  b 1 2 1 1
  c 1 1 1 0
  d 0 1 0 1

$II

    a b c d
  a 1 1 1 0
  b 1 1 1 0
  c 1 1 2 1
  d 0 0 1 1

$III

    a b c d
  a 2 0 1 1
  b 0 0 0 0
  c 1 0 1 1
  d 1 0 1 1
```

**EDIT:** My apologies I missed that you wanted to write each one out to a file.  I did this but you may want to consider the `save` or `saveRDS` functions with the output of the above function rather than writing multiple txt files:

```
v <- split(dat[, 2:3], dat[, 1])    
Output <- lapply(seq_along(v), function(i) {
        X <- table(v[[i]][, 2], v[[i]][, 1])    
        X <- as.matrix(X)    
        z <- X %*% t(X)
        write.table(z, paste0("coocurrence_group", names(v)[i], ".txt"),sep="\t")
        return(z)
    }
)

names(Output) <- names(v)
Output
```